# Andridplot how is it possible to change the window size dynamically without affecting the speed of plotting?

Tags: android, androidplot

I am using Androiplot Linechart for plotting real time data for plotting 240 points in a second. I am using the Domain boundary as 3 seconds(that means 720 points will be plotted in a window). I am using a seekbar to change the window size from 1 to 10 seconds. If the seekbar changes to 10, my domain boundary will be 2400.

Now the issue is that as the Domain boundary getting larger the plotting is getting very slow. There is no other change other that the Domain change. Could someone please help me to figure out why suddenly there is delay in plotting as the window size goes larger

Answer (score 0):

Aside from adding an artificial delay into you app at the time where you are plotting less data, to keep a constant frame rate, its not going to be possible to process and render an increasing amount of data at a constant rate.

There are things you can do to speed up the render speed, but at the end of the day, rendering will still get slower as the size of the data to render increases.

I'd suggest using something like [decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)) to shrink your dataset a constant size and render that down-sampled dataset instead.  There are quite a few ways to do it and the approach you take really depends on what you are modeling.

Comment: I need to plot the heart rate and I dont think I can use down-sampled dataset for the monitoring the heart rate.